# Does R have thrift bindings?

Tags: r, thrift

[Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/) is a way to declare data types and interfaces. You can compile the thrift into many other languages, called "bindings."  Is there a compiler than can produce an R binding for thrift?  I don't see one.

Comment: There is none (yet). But to my knowledge R is able to use C/C++ libaries?

Comment: Good point! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Still in its early adoption phase, but you can try: thriftr

```
service PingPong {
    string ping(),
}
```

Server:

```
library(thriftr)

pingpong_thrift = thriftr::t_load("pingpong.thrift", 
module_name="pingpong_thrift")

Dispatcher <- R6::R6Class("Dispatcher",
    public = list(
        ping = function() {
            return('pong')
        }
    )
)

server = thriftr::make_server(pingpong_thrift$PingPong, Dispatcher$new(), 
    '127.0.0.1', 6000)
server$serve()
```

Client:

```
library(thriftr)

pingpong_thrift = thriftpy::t_load("pingpong.thrift", 
module_name="pingpong_thrift")

client = thriftpy::make_client(pingpong_thrift$PingPong, "127.0.0.1", 6000)
cut(client$ping())
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI, the bindings I'm most interested in are the enum constants. We use thrift to share those across languages.

Comment: In theory, this library should also handle enums. I haven't tested it in real usecase scenario yet. You can check tests and demos here: https://github.com/systemincloud/thriftr